# how to set a state in function components depending on changehandler

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I have this Body Component set:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import {Container} from "react-bootstrap";
import Navigation from './Navigation'
import axios from 'axios'
import {useState,useEffect} from "react";


function Body() {
    const [searchItems, setSearchItems] = useState([{}])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(searchItems)
    }, [])

    return (
        <Container>
            <Navigation setSearchItems={setSearchItems}/>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Body;
```

And here is my Navigation Component with an Inputfield as anther component named SearchInput. As you can see I pass the setSearchItems from the start to each child, because I want to use the searchItems-Array to display some data later:

```
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import {InputGroup} from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from 'axios';
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const api_key = process.env.API_KEY;

const SearchInput = (setSearchItems) => {
    async function changeHandler(e, setSearchItems) {
        if (e.target.value.length > 2) {
            const url = 'https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search?q=' + e.target.value
            const config = {
                method: 'GET',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'x-api-key': api_key
                }
            }
            const data = await axios.get(url, config)
            setSearchItems(data['data'])
        }
    }

    return (
        <InputGroup style={{
            marginLeft: '50px',
            marginRight: '50px',
            paddingTop: '10px',
            paddingBottom: '10px',
            width: '50%'
        }}>
            <Form.Control
                placeholder="Enter Dogs Breed"
                aria-label="Breed"
                onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e, setSearchItems)}
            />
        </InputGroup>
    )
}

const Navigation = (setSearchInput) => {
    return (
        <Navbar fixed="top" bg='light'>
            <SearchInput setSearchInput={setSearchInput}/>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default Navigation;
```

everytime I try to call setSearchItems, I get **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setSearchItems is not a function**

I also tried this version of changeHandler before:

```
async function changeHandler(e) {
    if (e.target.value.length > 2) {
        const url = 'https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search?q=' + e.target.value
        const config = {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'x-api-key': api_key
            }
        }
        await axios.get(url, config)
            .then((response) => setSearchItems([response.data]))
    }
}
```

but it's an error al the time

Comment: `setSearchInput` and `setSearchItems` are separate things. Also if you want to pass props to your components and use them directly by their names, you should either destruct them or use `props.propName` and accept `props` as the function parameter in your components.

Comment: You have to use `({setSearchItems})` if you want to pass it as a prop. Check [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: I wish I could Flag these too Answers as Correct and Helpful. This is it. thank you for being so attentive, both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the concept of prop drilling in React by passing the props from parent to child component and getting values from child components. In your case, `Body` is the body component so you can basically `drill` the states through components.

So, your `Body` component looks like this

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Navigation from "./navigation";
import { useState } from "react";

function Body() {
  const [searchItems, setSearchItems] = useState([]);
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

  return (
    <Container>
      <Navigation
        setSearchItems={setSearchItems}
        setSearchInput={setSearchInput}
      />
      <ul>
        {searchItems.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Body;
```

and the `Navigation` component is

```
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import SearchInput from "./search";

const Navigation = ({ setSearchItems, setSearchInput }) => {
  return (
    <Navbar fixed="top" bg="light">
      <SearchInput
        setSearchInput={setSearchInput}
        setSearchItems={setSearchItems}
      />
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

and finally `Search` component is getting the `setSearchItems` as prop and adding the array to it.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
const api_key = process.env.API_KEY;

const SearchInput = ({ setSearchItems }) => {
  async function changeHandler(e) {
    if (e.target.value.length > 2) {
      const url =
        "https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search?q=" + e.target.value;
      const config = {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
          "x-api-key": api_key
        }
      };
      const data = await axios.get(url, config);
      console.log(data);

      setSearchItems(data["data"]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <InputGroup
      style={{
        marginLeft: "50px",
        marginRight: "50px",
        paddingTop: "10px",
        paddingBottom: "10px",
        width: "50%"
      }}
    >
      <Form.Control
        placeholder="Enter Dogs Breed"
        aria-label="Breed"
        onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e)}
      />
    </InputGroup>
  );
};

export default SearchInput;
```

I have added the working demo version [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-bogdan-742g92?file=/src/search.jsx:0-1009).

Comment: This is a really qualified Answer. Thanks a lot. The problem although was that I one named setSearchItems into setSearchINPUT and missed placing them in curley braces like this {setSearchItems}

Comment: I'd prefer to flag the two comments under my OP but this is also not wrong thank you for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try destructuing it in parameters of component like this: const Component =({setSearchItems}) => {}. It could work because the object that is given to component is actually params that holds all arguments